# Powershell Script that will login into powershell for office 365

Tags: actionscript-3, powershell, office365

I'm trying to find more information on getting a script for windows powershell script that will login to powershell for office 365 that will prompt for a user's administrator credentials. I'm not of key words I can search for this but I haven't found much information on it, please lend a hand guys. I don't just want a script that will do it, I'm looking for information on it too and how it works.

Comment: If my understanding is right, you want to launch office 365 from powershell and when launching office 365 it prompt for users' crendentials. Correct?

Comment: yes I found something along these lines       $cred = Get-Credential
$s = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange –ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic –AllowRedirection
$importresults = Import-PSSession $s

Comment: @user2596912 If you have answered the question yourself, it is preferred if you write in as an answer, rather than a comment so other users with the same question can more easily find your answer.

Answer (score 2):

For the exchange powershell use:

$SecPass1 = convertto-securestring -asplaintext -string "PasSword" -force
$MSOLM = new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist "GlobalAdmin@some.com",$SecPass1
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $MSOLM -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-Module MSOnline
Import-PSSession $Session –AllowClobber

Answer (score 1):

This script will prompt for credentials and login to OFfice 365 as admin:

```
To Login:


$LiveCred = Get-Credential
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange-ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $LiveCred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session
```

If you have more tasks to do than just logging in, I might be able to help you with the script as I've searched for and written many of them for Office 365.